# Requested factory com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory cannot be located

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, axis

I am trying to generate webservice client using axix2 on Eclipse
so I followed [the tutorial here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftaxis2client.html).

but at the last step when clicking finish, I am getting the error:

> Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Requested factory com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory cannot be located.  Classloader =org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@2de030

So I downloaded `wstx-asl-4.0.0.jar` and added it to the build path of the project, but still keep getting same error.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I got same issue but: I restart eclipse and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I ve got the same issue  but:
I place the jar in WEB-INF/lib , check that it is also in build path 
and restart eclipse

Without restarting eclipse I was stucked like you.

Hope that help